# How do I say 'Only print if value has changed since previous printed row'

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot-table

In reality these fields are not '1' they are big long strings. My goal here, is to have a c++ program parse this data into hierarchical objects. so I want the query to run as fast as possible, while returning the minimum ammount of data for me to be able to use to fill in the objects.

The following is how, in my imagination, this goal could be accomplished, but if there's a simpler way to accomplish the true goal, i'm all ears.

Other things i thought about:
I considered a pivot table, but if each tier of the hierarchy had 5 branches, by the time we get to the data we'd have 3000+ columns in our pivot table.

I want to concat 2 fields together, then listagg them, all while 
grouping by tiered header fields, and only printing fields if they are not 
the same as the previously printed row.

```
input
tier1,tier2,tier3,tier4,tier5,data1,data2
1     1     1     1     1     big   tall
1     1     1     1     1     big   smelly
1     1     1     1     2     gross   tall
1     1     1     2     1     flatulent exceptional


desired output:
1     1     1     1     1     big,tall big,smelly                                  
                        2     gross,tall
                  2     1     flatulent,exceptional
```

imaginary function which only prints a field if it has changed since the last printed row, we will call it crazy()

```
  select 
    crazy(tier1),
    crazy(tier2),
    crazy(tier3),
    crazy(tier4),
    crazy(tier5),
    listagg(data1||data2, ' ') within group(?)
  from table
  group by tier1,tier2,tier3,tier4,tier5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will know the columns, then you could potentially use a CTE (depending on what version of SQL you are using). If that will not work, then I would suggest just doing your work in the code. SQL is meant for SET-based logic, and not procedures and functions (Even though they are supported). The performance of running 5 or 6 functions on every row will be horrible in comparison to running your analysis in code